# Could someone explain how to configure nhibernate5.1 in dotnet core 2.0 project

Tags: nhibernate, .net-core

As nhibernate5.1 supports dotnet core2.0, we are trying to use nhibernate 5.1 in our dotnet core 2.0 api project. Don't find any documentation on how to configure nhibernate5.1 in dotnet core 2.0 project. Could someone guide me on  the same.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate GitHub repository has a minimal web (not API) application example showing how to use it with .Net Core. See [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/5.1.2/src/NHibernate.Example.Web).